# How do you order meta tags added by drupal_add_html_head()?

Tags: theming, 7

I'm adding Open Graph support to a Drupal site and I have a bunch of drupal_add_html_head() calls, like:

```
  $og_title = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:title', 
      'content' => $node->title,
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_title, 'zujava_og_title');

 $og_url = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:url', 
      'content' => url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_url, 'zujava_og_url');
```

In total, I have 10 of these. They don't seem to output in the same order they are called (all in a single function).

Is there some kind of weighting I can use to set the order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the #weight property. As [drupal_get_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_html_head/7) uses [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) to render the meta tags, #weight is used when rendering them.

I uses the following code to make a test on my local site; it is the same code you are using, except it doesn't have any reference to the node object.

```
  $og_title = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:title', 
      'content' => "This is the title",
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_title, 'zujava_og_title');

 $og_url = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:url', 
      'content' => url('node/1', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_url, 'zujava_og_url');

  dsm(drupal_get_html_head());
```

The output I got is the following one.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://tero.local/dr72/node/1" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title" />
```

As you see, the last added tag is the first to appear.

I then run the following code.

```
  $og_title = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:title', 
      'content' => "This is the title",
    ),
    '#weight' => 10,
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_title, 'zujava_og_title');

 $og_url = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:url', 
      'content' => url('node/1', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    ),
    '#weight' => 200,
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($og_url, 'zujava_og_url');

  dsm(drupal_get_html_head());
```

The output I got is the following one.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://tero.local/dr72/node/1" />
```

As you see, the order of the meta tags has been changed; the meta tags added from the code appear after the default meta tags added from Drupal.

[_drupal_default_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_default_html_head/7) (the function that returns the default meta tags) uses #weight for the "Content-Type" meta tag.

```
  $elements['system_meta_content_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag', 
    '#tag' => 'meta', 
    '#attributes' => array(
      'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type', 
      'content' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    ),
    // Security: This always has to be output first. 
    '#weight' => -1000,
  );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! THis worked. It seems like I missed something very obvious somewhere. For my own education, where did you find this documented?

Comment: Once I noticed the meta tags are rendered with `drupal_render()`, I have tried to see if #weight was used, as it is used for form elements which are rendered through the same function. The documentation for `drupal_render()` says: "Elements are sorted internally using uasort()."